# Is it possible to continue haar training in opencv?

Tags: c++, opencv, haar-classifier

opencv_traincascade.exe from opencv package has -numStage parameter and for each stage creates temporary xml file. When all stages are finished, the tool unifies thus xml files to cascade.xml.

The question is how to continue learning process from last stage using temporary xml files?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible and it performs automatically when running opencv_traincascade.exe next time